# NodeJS Error read ECONNRESET

Tags: php, node.js

If i am sending data from php to nodejs I get this error on my console:

[image]

How can I fix that error?

That's my code in nodejs:

```
var Server = net.createServer(function(Sock) {   
Sock.on('data', function(data) {       
   dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
   logger.info("received data");
});

Sock.pipe(Sock);
});
```

and thats my php code:

```
$data = array('xxx' => 'xxx');

$encdata = json_encode($data);

socket_write($socket, $encdata, strlen($encdata));

socket_close($socket);
```

Comment: Please copy the text from your console so that we can read the message and/or paste it into a search engine to help you.

Comment: Also, can you share any of your code? If the code is in the image, imagine that your problem is super rare and the one person who can help you doesn't have time to click on the link and wait for it to load to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

As it says `unhandled ´error´ event`, you can try to handle it to see what is causing the error. Something like this:

```
Sock.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is may be because you are closing your php socket earlier even before your client is getting the data.

As, econnreset normally results from a loss of the connection on the remote socket due to a timeout or reboot.
So, my suggestion would be to wait for sometime before closing the socket connection.